# ide-connected iomega zip drive freezes my system

Tags: floppy, lockup

I want to copy the data out of my old [Iomega Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_drive) disks while I still have the hardware to read them (and the disks themselves are still readable). To this end I dug out some old Zip drives and found one external SCSI/parallel (it would do both) and two internal IDE ones. I also dug out an old PCI SCSI card and suitable cable, but couldn't get the SCSI drive to work. But fortunately the IDE drives seemed to do fine for a few transfers.

The bad news is that they cause the system to hang: mouse stops moving, no response to keyboard and the only resort is power-cycling. This tends to happen:

1. when initiating a transfer from the second zip drive to the hard disk while the first drive is already transferring; or
2. when clicking the eject button in Nautilus after having completed a transfer, in an attempt to be well-behaved about unmounting the disk

I can avoid doing 1, though it kind of defeats the benefit of having two drives; but I have a harder time not doing 2.

Can anyone guess a reason why the zip drives would hang the system, and more importantly a way to avoid this?

Comment: Do the logs have any information? Even after (re)boot you will probably find some info in /var/log/kern.log,

Comment: I went in to check and now the system won't even boot. I tried rescue mode and it didn't even get there, locking up after having declared "[OK] Started uded Kernel Device Manager". Hmm. Looks like I have a more serious problem now. Let me disconnect the IDE-ATAPI zip drives altogether and try again...

Comment: @Eduardo Trápani OK, I am back in. In /var/log/kern.log there are a LOT of "usb 6-1.2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd". Like one per second forever from some point onwards. But this does not look related because (a) the Zip drives were not USB-connected and (b) I am still getting them now this morning after having totally disconnected the IDE cable.

Comment: @Eduardo Trápani I have searched the log for iomega or zip and they are only mentioned when the drives got recognised: nothing looking like errors nearby. I have also ascertained that usb 6-1 is my usb 3.0 hub to which the external HDD onto which the data was being backed up was attached. No idea why it needs resetting once per second but it is still happening now if I tail -f /var/log/kern.log.

Comment: @Eduardo Trápani I power-cycled the usb hub and the one-per-second kernel messages about it stopped.

Comment: Power cycled the computer. tail -f kern.log. Still a message per second of usb blabla. Disconnected the hard drive from that usb hub and reconnected it directly to a usb 3.0 card on the computer. Messages stopped. Switched off computer. Reconnected one zip drive to ide as master. Powered on. Boot went fine. None of these kernel messages about usb. Hard disk recognised fine. Zip drive too, by the look of the kernel messages. Inserted a disk in the zip drive. Computer locked up (earlier than other times: no chance to see or copy any files).

Comment: "sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR drive byte=DRIVER_OK" was one of the last kernel messages on tail -f.

Comment: If the drives are ok ... there might be a compatibiliy issue with the motherboard. There is more than one type of IDE (33/66/100), maybe you have the wrong one. That could explain that detection goes well (relatively low bandwith) and copying does not. I would check that, that there is no IDE mismatch.

Comment: The motherboard is an Asus P8H67-V which, its documentation says, supports Ultra DMA 133/100. So far I was not able to find documentation saying what transfer speed the Z250ATAPI drive is rated at, but I'd be really surprised if it exceeded that. Hmm.

Comment: Come to think of it, I must have bought the zip drive around 2000 or slightly earlier, and the motherboard in 2010 or slightly later, so I'm pretty damn certain that the transfer rate of the zip drive cannot exceed that accepted by the motherboard. I can't find out whether the motherboard accepts lower speeds, though I would have guessed yes.